# Drupal 7 multiple views are shown on one page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-views

just a quick one, im sure its very easy although it is drving me crazy.

I have a custom theme that i have developed. I have developed a few different views. For some reason my blog and colorbox are showing on both the colorbox and blog pages that i have created.

I only want the Colorbox views to be displayed on one page and the other view to be shown on its own page. For some reason they both display on the same page.

THanks for looking into this guys!

Answer (score 2):

In which method you have displayed the view? is it in BLOCK or PAGE?? this might be page i think. so please edit the block and make sure it is not listed in all pages

Comment: Hello THank you for your reply, i have the url which is /colorbox and /blog. 

The links in the top navigation are pointing to these links. I went into the block and put in the url to only display this block on the defined page. The home page and other basic pages are also listing under it for some reason.

Comment: Please be sure which option you have selected... All pages expected those listed (or) All pages listed below?